# How much time has passed since the events in Max Payne 2?

Tags: max-payne-3

In Max Payne 3 we're not given a timeframe that sets the action in a specified year. Is it stated anywhere how much time has passed since the events in Max Payne 2? Max looks like he has aged, but it can be because of his bad habits... Has it been months? Years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Max Payne Wiki](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Payne_3) the third game is set 8 years after the end of the second game.